# SPI setBitOrder question

Tags: arduino, spi

This is more of the technical, i would try to test it via trial and error but i don't have extra equipment. Anyways, firstly if i set the SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFirst) transfer the command, for example 0b11110000 the "1s" are to be sent first, right? MSB is supposed to be transmitted on the first clock cycle based on the datasheet.

Does it comply both ways? if i were to receive the data 0B11110000 then store it in a variable, would the position change? the device sends the MSB first.

Comment: A bit more background information would be helpful. What is the platform?

Comment: If it's as you describe (and perhaps more importantly, as I understand you) then yes if you specify to send the MSB first the byte 0b11110000 will be sent "1s" first and received "1s" first. But really, it would be more helpful if you told us what is sending and what is receiving

Comment: It might also be helpful if you included some code.

Answer (score 2):

All integrated SPI logic basically consists of a single shift register.

[image]

The image shows what happens if **LSB goes first**. Data is shifted right, at the master side LSB goes first out to MOSI, and at the same time the slave's LSB is shifted in at the left. Eight clock pulses later that same LSB has travelled through the whole shift register and arrive at the master's LSB.

If **MSB goes first** it means that data is shifted left, at the master side MSB goes first out to MOSI, and at the same time the slave's MSB is shifted in at the right. Eight clock pulses later same MSB has travelled through the whole shift register and arrive at the master's MSB.

So, yes, MSB first goes for both sending and receiving. The bidirectional shift register, allowing both MSB first and LSB first is a feature of the SPI hardware in the AVR controllers. Other manufacturers use a fixed shift direction. If your data is as long as the shift register then in most cases the shift direction will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino [SetBitOrder](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPISetBitOrder) function in the SPI library sets the order for both bits clocked in and out.